# check if first and last character of each word in a string is same

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the set of names where 1st & last letter of each part of name(first name, middle name, last name) matches. A name can have 5 parts.
If names are:

```
croc lil brob tart
cron lee bro tasr
```

It should result:

```
croc lil brob tart

Declare @name as varchar(70) = 'cron lee bro tasr test'
    Select @name, Substring(@name,1,1) As "First letter of First Name",
    Substring(@name,charindex(' ',@name) +1 -2,1) As "Last letter of First Name",
    Substring(@name,charindex(' ',@name) +1 ,1) As "First letter of Second Name",
    Substring(@name,charindex(' ',@name, charindex(' ',@name) + 1) +1 -2 ,1) As "Last letter of Second Name",
    Substring(@name,charindex(' ',@name, charindex(' ',@name) + 1) +1 ,1) As "First letter of Third Name",
    Substring(@name,charindex(' ',@name, charindex(' ',@name,charindex(' ',@name) + 1) + 1 +1)+1 -2 ,1) AS "Last Letter of 3rd Name",
    Substring(@name,charindex(' ',@name, charindex(' ',@name,charindex(' ',@name) + 1) + 1 +1)+1 ,1) AS "First Letter of 4th Name",
    Substring(@name,charindex(' ',@name,charindex(' ',@name, charindex(' ',@name,charindex(' ',@name) + 1) + 1 +1)+1)+1 -2 ,1) AS "Last Letter of 4th Name",
    Substring(@name,charindex(' ',@name,charindex(' ',@name, charindex(' ',@name,charindex(' ',@name) + 1) + 1 +1)+1)+1 ,1) AS "first Letter of 5th Name",
    SUBSTRING(Reverse(@name),1,1) AS "Last letter of 5th Name" WHERE 
    Substring(RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),1,1) = Substring(RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1)) +1 -2,1) OR 
    Substring(RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1)) +1 ,1) = Substring(RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1), charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1)) + 1) +1 -2 ,1) OR 
    Substring(RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1), charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1)) + 1) +1 ,1) = Substring(RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1), charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1)) + 1) + 1 +1)+1 -2 ,1) OR
    Substring(RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1), charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1)) + 1) + 1 +1)+1 ,1) = 
    Substring(RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1), charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1)) + 1) + 1 +1)+1)+1 -2 ,1) OR
    Substring(RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1), charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1),charindex(' ',RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1)) + 1) + 1 +1)+1)+1 ,1) = SUBSTRING(Reverse(RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + @name)) - 1)),1,1)
```

By this select query I am able to get the first & last character of each part of name. But, I am confused with the where clause.

Comment: **Hint:** you can use `LEFT` and `RIGHT`

Comment: A perfect example of a problem unsuited to the strengths of SQL Server. There are plenty of languages with strong string processing features, such as regular expressions. T-SQL isn't one of them. Why does it "have" to be done in SQL?

Comment: are you using any server side scripting ?? then it is better to do this there . or first you have to split the string based on space then use something like this select * from tablename where right(columnname,1)=left(columnname,1)

Comment: @TimSchmelter it is omitted because tasr dosen't end with a t.

Comment: This data seriously needs to be normalized. This would be 2 or 3 lines of code if each name was in its own column.

Comment: This is a question I faced to solve using sql queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Split-Function, then it's relatively easy:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM  dbo.Split(t.Col, ' ')x
   WHERE LEFT(x.Item, 1) <> RIGHT(x.Item, 1)
)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d4426e/1/0)</kbd>

Here's one that i use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @ItemList NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @ItemTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(250))  
AS      

BEGIN    
    DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

    DECLARE @i INT    
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

    WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @i = 0
            SET @Item = @tempItemList
        ELSE
            SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
        INSERT INTO @ItemTable(Item) VALUES(@Item)
        IF @i = 0
            SET @tempItemList = ''
        ELSE
            SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(id INT, t VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 'croc lil brob tart'),
(2, 'cron lee bro tasr')


;WITH cte AS(
SELECT id,
       Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS t  
FROM  
(   
    SELECT id, CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(t, ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML ) AS t FROM @t
) AS A CROSS APPLY t.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))

SELECT * FROM @t t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM cte WHERE id = t.id AND LEFT(t, 1) <> RIGHT(t, 1))
```

Output:

```
id  t
1   croc lil brob tart
```